# CloudWatch alarm with GROUP BY statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following CloudWatch metric that detect pods restarting:

```
SELECT SUM(pod_number_of_container_restarts) FROM SCHEMA(ContainerInsights,
ClusterName,FullPodName,Namespace,PodName) WHERE ClusterName='cluster-123' 
AND Namespace='namespace-123' GROUP BY FullPodName ORDER BY MAX() DESC LIMIT 10
```

This produces a nice graph that looks like this:

[image]

Notice that this breaks down which pods are restarting

However, when I try to create an alarm, I get the error:

> You cannot create an alarm on a Metric Query that has a GROUP BY statement

When I take away the GROUP by statement, I can create the alarm, but my alarm does not break down which pods are restarting and instead looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to create the CloudWatch alarm that has the `GROUP BY` or some other way of associating which pods are restarting?